# How would you associate a work item to a previous check-in in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I checked-in my codes in TFS but I forgot to associate a work item. I tried to go to check-in history and opened the check-in change set details but when I clicked on the Work Items button, it says that there is no work items associated and it does not give me an option to associate one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it the other way around; open the work item and add a link to the relevant changeset. If using the default work item templates:

1. Get the changeset ID by looking at the History of one of the changed files
2. Open the relevant work item
3. Select the Links tab
4. Click the Add button
5. Select "Changeset" from the Link type dropdown
6. Enter the changeset ID (from step 1) into the Changeset field, and click OK
7. Save the work item

Granted, it won't say "Resolved with changeset XXX" in the work item's history, but the work item **will** appear in the changeset's list of associated work items.

Comment: In TFS 2010, associating a changeset this way adds it to the history. At least it happened with my TFS configuration and following your steps. Thanks!